# Undefined reference: dll -> free function -> overloaded operator -> templated struct

Tags: c++, vector, operator-overloading, undefined-reference

I can't build the right words for it to call, so I made the title like that.

I have this DLL in which the `template`d `struct`s are inside in a `namespace` with defined *overloaded operators* that are non-member(free function) of those `struct`s.

**"VectorX.h"**

```
#ifdef SPECS
#define SPECS __declspec(dllimport)
#else
#define SPECS __declspec(dllexport)
#endif // SPECS

namespace swc
{
    template <typename T>
    struct Vec3 : Vec2<T>
    {
        Vec3();
        Vec3(T value); //*1
        Vec3& operator = (const T scalar); //*1
        ...
        Vec3& operator += (const Vec3<T> &v);
        Vec3& operator += (const T scalar);

        //*1 w/c of this two are used when I do `Vec3<T> v = 0.0f;` ??
    };

    //What attribute should I use to make this works?
    //It's compiling but it cause undefined reference when I use it.
    //Or I have many ambiguous calls here(?)

    template<typename T>
    /* SPECS, static, extern */ Vec3<T> const operator * (const Vec3<T> &v, const T scalar);
    template<typename T>
    /* SPECS, static, extern */  Vec3<T> const operator * (const T scalar, const Vec3<T> &v);

    typedef Vec3<float> Vec3f;
}
```

then I tried to use it

**"test.cpp"**

```
#include <iostream>

#include "../../VectorX/vectorx.h"

using namespace swc;

Vec3f CalculateBezierPoint(float t, const Vec3f &p0, const Vec3f &p1, const Vec3f &p2, const Vec3f &p3);

int main()
{
    ...
}

Vec3f CalculateBezierPoint(float t, const Vec3f &p0, const Vec3f &p1, const Vec3f &p2, const Vec3f &p3)
{
    float u = 1 - t;
    float tt = t * t;
    float uu = u * u;
    float uuu = uu * u;
    float ttt = tt * t;

    Vec3f p = uuu; //is it the operator '=' or the constructor Vec3f(T value)?
    //**this is where the compiler starts complaining about undefined references.**
    p += 3 * uu * t * p1;
    p += 3 * u * tt * p2;
    p += ttt * p3;

    return p0;
}
```

this one works `p += 3 * 2 * 1;` but this one doesn't `p += 3 * 2 * 1 * p1;`

I think it is due to the declaration of the **overloaded operator of free function** inside the `namespace` I made that causes the error but I don't know what else to do.

Answer (score 3):

When you initialize a variable being declared, like in

```
Vec3f p = uuu;
```

you invoke the *copy constructor*. That is, a constructor of the format

```
Vec3(const Vec3<T> &v);
```

Normally the compiler can auto-generate such a constructor, but if there are any other non-standard constructor (like the `Vec3(T value);` one) the compiler will not do that. That means that you try to invoke the copy-constructor when there is none.

If you don't have control of the `Vec3` class, and so can't add the copy-constructor, you have to use the assignment instead:

```
Vec3f p;
p = uuu;
```

Comment: I only made that constructor because it doesn't work when I overload the `operator =`, I definitely erase that later on after I solved some of these problems. Thanks for the answer btw :)